# Who causes redirect: Tomcat or ICEFaces?

Tags: tomcat, redirect, jsf-1.2, icefaces-1.8

Using ICEFaces 1.8.2 and Tomcat 6.0.24 I created a single jspx page. This page contains three input fields only and a few output texts. The page reloads itself every 10 minutes because of a meta refresh.

When I open the page in FireFox 23 and leave it open for some time, then the page gets redirected to a non-existing URL, which causes the error page to be shown. The URL buildserver/proef/terminal/sample... is redirected to buildserver/proef/terminal/inal/sample...

My question is: what causes the page to be redirected to the wrong URL? Is it a problem with Tomcat or ICEFaces?

I am not using Apache's webserver to redirect HTTP traffic to Tomcat. I even saw the redirection happen when running Tomcat in Eclipse.

Here is a summary of the communication between the browser and Tomcat captured with Wireshask:

```
GET /proef/terminal/sample_label_print.jspx?location=004-PRODEE HTTP/1.1

Host: buildserver
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Cookie: JSESSIONID=57AC0E6B2F86B115AE984F3B7E7FBA93; ice.sessions=; updates=; ice.lease=1380208450505; JSESSIONID.8be0fa73=1f4e10ca702da469c4b0c37f42905d6a; screenResolution=1680x1050; JSESSIONID.48b2edef=c66cf618a1d31a7cef66687c8f6c0550; bconn=Bv54BVUkcK2uDN4y25NcvA:50:acquired
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Location: http://buildserver/proef/terminal/inal/sample_label_print.jspx
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 26 Sep 2013 15:14:06 GMT


GET /proef/terminal/inal/sample_label_print.jspx HTTP/1.1

Host: buildserver
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Cookie: JSESSIONID=57AC0E6B2F86B115AE984F3B7E7FBA93; ice.sessions=; updates=; ice.lease=1380208450505; JSESSIONID.8be0fa73=1f4e10ca702da469c4b0c37f42905d6a; screenResolution=1680x1050; JSESSIONID.48b2edef=c66cf618a1d31a7cef66687c8f6c0550; bconn=Bv54BVUkcK2uDN4y25NcvA:50:acquired
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0


HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 26 Sep 2013 15:14:06 GMT
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the cause of the problem myself. In my web.xml I specified two url-patterns: /abc/* for which authorization is required and /terminal/* for which authorization is not required:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/abc/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/terminal/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

Scenario to reproduce the problem:

- Open two pages in one browser: abc/one.jspx and /terminal/two.jspx
- Log in abc/one.jspx
- Switch to terminal/two.jspx and trigger an action
- Now terminal/two.jspx is redirected to terminal/inal/two.jspx

I sovled the problem by changing the URL-patterns in web.xml so that they have the same length: instead of `/terminal/*` I used `/trm/*`.

Tomcat mixes the URL-patterns. Is this a bug in Tomcat or an undocumented feature?